# IntelliJ build mixed Groovy and Java project fails with cannot find symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a mixed (Java & Groovy) IntelliJ project. My Groovy class is using an @Builder annotation. I can access the builder from Java but it fails during the build process of the project with the failure...

```
Error:(27, 105) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method builder()
location: class foo.bar.Sample
```

If I comment out the use of the builder, the project builds perfectly fine and I can see the builder in the resulting class file.

I think the problem is the build order, that javac tries to compile my Java code before the Groovy code is compiled.

Any idea how to fix this?

The IntelliJ version is Community 2017.1.2

*** Update ***

I try to be more verbose about my project...it is set up like this...

The source roots are:

[image: Project source roots]

The DataObject groovy class:

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Builder
class DataObject {
    String message 
}
```

And the MainClass...

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(DataObject.builder().message("HelloWorld!").build().getMessage());

        DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.setMessage("HelloWorld!");
        System.out.println(dataObject.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Groovy-Eclipse is set as the Java Compiler (groovy-eclipse-batch-2.4.3-01.jar) in the bytecode version 1.8

If I try to compile the the project I got the following Error...[image: Build error]

I get a similar error (java:cannot find symbel for the builder) if I try it with javac as the Java compiler.

If I remove the use of the builder from Java class, the project builds perfectly and I am able to use the builder, at least as long I don't have any changes on the groovy class.

Comment: You need to show how are you build it. Consider `groovyc` instead of `javac`

Comment: I am not sure what to show/describe exactly. I use Build Project (Ctrl+F9). Java compiler is Javac (1.8)  to build the project . I also tried Groovy-Eclipse but it lead to other erros (in combination with generics and lambda streams). Nothing is set at Groovy Compiler but the Groovy Framework is added to the project. 
How can I set groovyc as the compiler? I don't see that option at the Java Compiler screen

Comment: The usual fix for this scenario is to put your .java files under the source-root, that gets build with groovyc.  Groovyc just works as javac for .java files.

Comment: Actually I have two separate src folders...src/main/java and src/main/groovy .  You mean I should move my java files to the groovy root? Isn't there a way to disable the javac and just use the groovyc?

Comment: What build system do you use? How you project roots are configured? Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You are affected by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3683.

Assuming you've installed Groovy with [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/).

```
$ sdk use groovy 2.4.9
Using groovy version 2.4.9 in this shell.

# This is the error you get using joint compilation
$ groovyc -j src/main/groovy/* 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/Users/danyjb/Downloads/GroovyTest/src/main/groovy/MainClass.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(DataObject.builder().message("HelloWorld!").build().getMessage());
                                     ^
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class DataObject
1 error
```

To resolve the problem you need to compile Groovy and Java separately:

```
$ groovyc src/main/groovy/DataObject.groovy -d out/
$ javac -cp $GROOVY_HOME/lib/groovy-2.4.9.jar:out/ -d out/ src/main/groovy/MainClass.java
```

In terms of IntelliJ IDEA this means you need to put your Groovy code in the separate module and add a dependency from the Java module to the Groovy module.